# Library for generating primitive shapes?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking for a library to generate the data for primitive shapes for opengl. I have lights, and I simply wants to draw a sphere to represent the lights transform in the world

I do not want a library that *draws* it though, I want to control all openGL-related API calls myself (so, freeGLUT is Not what Im looking for), I simply want to generate the vertices, normals, etc for a mesh shape at runtime (a cube, sphere, etc).

Is there any nice, minimal library that can do this task? If not, what is the alghoritm for generating vertices for a sphere-shape?

Thanks

EDIT: I am not looking to load from 3d model formats either

Comment: This falls under the category of a "which technology" or "list of X" type question I think, which aren't constructive here. Please see the [faq] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating simple geometry, a whole (even simple) library would be overkill.  You only need a handful of static constructors.  You could find any example code that draws shapes, and copy-paste those lines.  You may find what you need simply by examining freeGLUT's source code.

It would make more sense to use a model format parser.  Generating geometry data is their job.  You can create those shapes in any simple 3D editor, then file IO them into your running code.  You could create a sphere or cube with a few mouse clicks.  Or for something more exotic, you could use any of these: [list of common 3d test models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_3D_test_models)

Comment: I use a model format parser (assimp, specifically) for 3d models, but I want to draw primimtive shapes without loading from 3d formats (I shouldve said so, sorry). I'll look through freeGLUTs source, but if you find any other source code with it online I would be most grateful